# form submission in webpage confirmation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, html

the code below accepts the text in the form and insets it into the table.i wanted to it to add to the table and redirect to the same page after displaying the message "data has been added".But the problem is that it is getting redirected to the target page but not displaying the message.im guessing that is because the cmd.ExecuteQuery(); is generating a response and is getting redirected...

but i want it to show the message.
what changes should i do.thanks in advance

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string v = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["harish"].ConnectionString;
    con = new OracleConnection(v);
    con.Open(); 
    string query="insert into leave_module1 values(:name,:desig,:srno,:tol,:compdates,:fd,:td,:nod,:remarks)";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    //OracleCommand.BindByName = true;
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":name", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropDownList2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":desig", OracleType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox10.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":srno", OracleType.Number, 8).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":tol", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":compdates", OracleType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox9.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":fd", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":td", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":nod", OracleType.Number, 3).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":remarks", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation",
         "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Data has been added')</script>");
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");


    }
    catch
    {

        Label13.Visible = true;           

    }

    con.Close();    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Response.Redirect.

Just use javascript:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", 
     "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Data has been added'); window.location='default2.aspx';</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

that's happen because your code add the JS script to your starting page (let's say Default1.aspx) then you redirect to `Default2.aspx` which won't contain the JS code.

I would suggest you to pass a parameter(maybe using the QueryString) to the `Default2.aspx` page which will show the message.

I would not recommend you to use an `Alert` to show the message. You better use a div on your page or a JQuery plugin to show the message

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: actually im redirecting it to the same page so that all text fields are empty for the user to enter details again..so that is not feasible

Comment: if you are redirecting to the same page you might just empty the field after the insert instead of redirect to the same page. My suggestion to not to use an alert is still valid

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following to the javascript.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation",  
     "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Data has been added')</script>");
```

to this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation",  
     "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Data has been added');window.location="Default2.aspx" </script>");
```

and remove the following in your code

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to see the messsage on that page, you need to allow that page to be visible after inserting the data instead of redirecting immediately.  Instead of using the Server-Side Response.Redirect, you will need to use Javascript (client-side code) to redirect after a few seconds.  The delay is acheived using `setTimeout()` in Javascript.

The javascript necessary to do this is explained [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar by using the Session object instead of JavaScript. Maybe the idea will help you.

I have created a message variable in the master page and in a case like yours I would

- set the message variable with the necessary text
- redirect to the desired aspx page
- the master page checks if there is a message to be displayed. If yes, it shows a panel and resets the variable

In your case the panel could have an OK or CLOSE button or you could use other objects from the Ajax Control Toolkit.